# How to enable Edge Protect in iPhone X?

Tags: ios, iphone, gesture

I would like enable Edge Protection to my iOS game, so that the players do not leave the game to the menu of the iPhone without wanting.

In developer.apple explains that we should enable Edge Protection, but does not explain how:

In rare cases, immersive apps like games might require custom screen-edge gestures that take priority over the system's gestures—the first swipe invokes the app-specific gesture and a second-swipe invokes the system gesture. This behavior (known as edge protect) should be implemented sparingly, as it makes it harder for people to access the system-level actions.

https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/user-interaction/gestures/

Answer (score 3):

Add Code below to your UIViewController

```
-(UIRectEdge)preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures
{
    return UIRectEdgeAll;
}
```